# Update cell value in Google Sheet and get updated answer without saving

Tags: node.js, google-sheets

I'm using the [google-sheets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) node package to interact with my spreadsheet in my Google Drive. I want to update a cell and then get another cell's value which uses a formula. I don't want to save the spreadsheet, I just want to be able to update values and get outcomes on the fly, then discard all changes when I have finished. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how formulas work using this technique, but you can always update with the old value (make two saves with updated and with old one). Stupid, but still kind of revert :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** No, there is no way to modify a private copy of a Google Spreadsheet. Instead, you could make a temporary copy of the spreadsheet, play with it, then delete it when finished.

---

Google Sheets doesn't really support the concept of "save", in the way that a desktop application like Microsoft Excel might. You need to remember that the spreadsheet is designed specifically for collaboration and sharing - even when only one user is involved. In order to support synchronization of multiple views of a spreadsheet, every change made by any user / editor is immediately applied and synced.

One possible work-around for your use case would be to create a copy of the spreadsheet, then open and experiment with that. This way, you get the result of your hypothetical change, while the original remains untouched.